# Create date with tiered hierarchy in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know there are multiple questions in Stackoverflow that say how to use current date as folder name, but I am looking for something different.

If today's date is `1/22/2017`, I want there to be three folders:

```
C:\2017
└───1
    └───22
```

The directory looks like `C:\2017\1\22\`.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you really want month (and perhaps also day) to consist of a single digit, hence no leading zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a batch with a similar setup,
you wil have to adapt the line
`Set "DailyPath=C:\Test\%yyyy%\%M%\%d%\"`
to beginn with your desired base.

```
:: CDx.cmd ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off & SetLocal
for /f "tokens=1delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
    ) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "yyyy=%_DT:~0,4%"
Set /A "M=1%_DT:~4,2% -100"
Set /A "d=1%_DT:~6,2% -100"
Set "DailyPath=C:\Test\%yyyy%\%M%\%d%\"
If not Exist "%DailyPath%" (Echo New %Dailypath%&md "%DailyPath%")
Endlocal&Cd /D "%DailyPath%"
```

Thats an alternative for powershell.

```
Function CD# {
  $DailyPath = "C:\Test\$(Get-Date -F "yyyy\\M\\d\\")"
  IF (!(Test-Path $DailyPath)) { mkdir $DailyPath|out-null }
  Set-Location $DailyPath
}
```